# Download Router extension for Firefox web browser

Tags: web-browser, web, firefox, download-manager

On Chrome, there is an extension called **Downloads Router**. Looking for something similar for Firefox. The Downloads Router allows you to automatically save your downloads to different folders based on a rule set. For example, I can create a rule to save all files download from `www.xyz.com` to `~/Downloads/xyz` folder.

This is the only thing preventing me from dumping the Chrome browser. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely dump Chrome... allow me to introduce you to [Firefox's **Save In...** extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/save-in/).

The summary on AMO is well written:

> Adds a context menu to save media {image, video, audio, link, selection, page} in user-defined directories relative to the default download location. Save into dynamically named directories. **Rules-based download renaming and routing.** [emphasis mine]

Voila!

And if you would also like to read a whole article written about the extension, [here is a nice one](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/03/15/save-in-switch-between-multiple-download-folders-in-firefox/).